# Are Microsoft SQL Server DB userIDs case sensitive?

Tags: sql-server, database, active-directory, case-sensitive

I'm logging in to a server through RDC and there we have an SQL Server instance.
I think SSO is activated here.

I connect to SQL Server Managenment Studio (SSMS) with windows authentication, I'm not able to connect to the database. (SSMS shows the logged in UserID is in UPPERCASE)

When I connect to SSMS by 'Run as different user' and put the same credentials I used to log in to this server (i.e. Windows credentials only), I can connect to the Database then! (SSMS shows the logged in UserID is in lowercase).

Can someone help why this is happening!? and what can be one to resolve it?

Comment: What do you mean by sayin "UserID"? ID is a number, it cannot be case sensitive/insensitive.

Comment: >>>I connect to SQL Server Managenment Studio (SSMS) with windows authentication, I'm not able to connect to the database. (SSMS shows the logged in UserID is in UPPERCASE)<<< How can SSMS show user in uppercase if you are not able to connect?

Comment: SQL Server is only case sensitive if you are using a Case Sensitive Collation.

Comment: It won't be case sensitive for windows authentication. Are you sure the user you are logged in as on the jump box is definitely the same user and same domain?

Comment: I checked with the admin team in the company. They gave the access to my ID through Active Directory.

I can connect to the Database if I login to the overlying DB Engine (SQL Instance) after 'Run as Different user' and USE THE SAME CREDENTIALS OF MY WINDOWS.

But I can't connect to the Databse if I normally login without running as different user. It's the same credentials!!

The Microsoft admin team also can't understand it here why this is happening.
I checked the collation also it's the same - Case Insensitive.

Comment: @sepupic userID is my Windows User ID or the the ID that is used in whole Microsoft Infrastructure including Databases and Office365 account. 
It goess something like: n325232.

Also, I SSMS shows user in Uppercase since I can connect to the SSMS Database Engine. But I can't access the Database lying inside.

Answer (score 0):

If it works when you use "Run as different user", that makes me think it's stale credentials.

Try logging out of the server. Don't just disconnect from RDP, but "Log off" (which will then automatically disconnect you). Then log back in and try again.

When you login, Windows creates a logon token that it passes around to anything that needs your credentials. Even if you disconnect from RDP, if you haven't "logged off", then your session is still active and so is your logon token.

When you try to authenticate to SQL Server, it uses your existing logon token. SQL Server then tries to verify your token with the domain controller and can't for whatever reason. Maybe your password has changed or something else on your account has changed since you last logged into the server.

When you use "Run as different user", it creates a new logon token.